# Monoid Ring of a Commutative Cancellative Ordered Monoid

Tags: ring-theory, representation-theory, order-theory, monoid

Suppose $M$ is a commutative cancellative monoid with $0$ as the identity and $+$ as the operation, and $M$ is equipped with an order $\preceq$ defined by
$$
m \preceq m' \text{ if and only if there exists } x \in M \text{ such that } m + x = m'.
$$
In order for $\preceq$ to be a partial order, no pair of non-zero elements $m, m'$ of $M$ can satisfy $m + m' = 0$. Assume this is the case. Then $0$ is the minimum of $M$.

My question is: If $R$ is an integral domain, will $R[M]$, the monoid ring of $M$, be an integral domain?

I tend to believe the answer is positive, but as I try to prove it, I am not sure anymore.

Comment: The [Kaplansky zerodivisor conjecture](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/79559/what-is-the-current-status-of-the-kaplansky-zero-divisor-conjecture-for-group-ri) seems relevant (although no nontrivial group has a partial order of the form you described)

Comment: Yes it is. You can always embed $M$ in its Grothendieck group $G$, and $G$ will inherit a partial order from $M$ defined similarly (replace $m$ and $m'$ by elements of $G$, but $x$ still has to be an element of $M$). I just think my problem seems so much simpler than many special cases of the conjecture studied. It might even have been solved. I just don't know the answer now...

Comment: Oh, if you require $x \in M$, then yes, the partial order extends to the Grothendieck group. Originally though, existence of the partial order implies that no non-identity elements have inverses, hence my previous comment. I'm also not sure that your problem is *much* simpler than the zerodivisor conjecture: the assumptions there are much stronger than in your problem